# How to create a new struct and use its original value as a member of the new struct

Tags: pointers, go, recursion, struct

I am trying to create a new struct and use its original value as a member of the new struct. However, they both end up being the same reference (i.e. `payload` and `payload.prev`) and it causes infinite recursion in my code. I appreciate any help or hint.

```
package main

type Sieve struct {
    prime int
    prev  *Sieve
}

func Test(payload *Sieve, n int) {
    if payload.prime*(n/payload.prime) == n {

    } else if payload.prev == nil {
        println(n)
        // payload and payload.prev end up being the same reference
        // and it causes infinite loop
        *payload = Sieve{
            prime: n,
            prev:  payload,
        }
    } else {
        Test(payload.prev, n)
    }
}

func main() {
    var p = Sieve{
        prev:  nil,
        prime: 2,
    }

    println(2)

    for i := 2; i < 10; i++ {
        Test(&p, i)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before overwriting the `Sieve` struct pointed by `payload` make a copy of it:

```
p := *payload
```

And now you can assign a new `Sieve` struct value, storing the address of the copy as its `prev` field:

```
*payload = Sieve{
    prime: n,
    prev:  &p,
}
```

With this change, your app runs and properly outputs the primes between 2 and 10 (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/KjHa8CH2N_l)):

```
2
3
5
7
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You want to update the "payload" pointer to point to the address of a new struct. Construct your new struct like this:

```
payload = &Sieve{
            prime: n,
            prev:  payload,
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

With this code below, you are not creating a new instance of `Sieve`, you are setting the existing instance of `Sieve` to point to itself:

```
*payload = Sieve{
            prime: n,
            prev:  payload,
        }
```

If you want to push the `payload` one level down, you can do this:

```
p:=*payload
*payload = Sieve {
  prime: n,
  prev: &p}
```

This will first assign the contents of `payload` to `p`, and then will rewrite `payload` contents to point to `p`.

On the other hand, if you want to create a new `payload` pointing to the old one, use:

```
payload = Sieve { 
   prime: n,
   prev: payload }
```

Then you have to return/use this new `payload` pointer.